# "Grew up" vs "Would grow up"

Tags: grammar, tense, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

> She didn't love him, however she had to put up with him till the kids ......... a bit more.

a. grew up 
b. would grow up

I think grammatically "b" is the correct choice here, nonetheless, I have my doubts whether I am right of wrong!
I was wondering if you could give me a hand with this question.

Comment: why do you think **would** is necessary?

Comment: Because it happened in an upcoming point of the time in the the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English speakers generally don't use the modals *will* or *would* inside temporal or conditional clauses, even where there is clear future meaning:

> *When I go* (not *when I will go*)

> *until she comes* (not *until she will come*)

> *If you see him* (not *if you will see him*)

and in the past

> *Until they grew up* (not *until they would grow up*).

There are exceptions, but only with special meanings for *will* and *would*, for example "Willing to": *If he will come* does not mean the same as *if he comes*, it means something like *if he agrees to come*.

Answer (score 1):

In your context, "would grow" is incorrect.

You can use "would" in a conditional statement, for example, "She would have left if the kids had been older". But you've already got a conditional statement - her leaving him is conditional on the kids growing up. Their growth is not conditional on anything. There is no doubt that the kids will grow.

"Would", the way you're using it, is the past tense of "will". For example, "she would grow to hate him" means that you already *know* that happened, but you're speaking about a situation before it did. That isn't the case in your example. If you really wanted to use "would" in this way, you should really say "*she would have to put up with him till the kids grew up a bit more*".